# Unable to add apache Nifi in ambari?

Tags: ambari, vmware-workstation, apache-nifi, vmware-player, hortonworks-sandbox

I am trying to add Apache Nifi in ambari but continuously failing with error Error occured during stack advisor command invocation:

```
Unable to delete directory /var/run/ambari-server/stack-recommendations/1.
```

There is a similar thread with the [same error](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/33127/i-cant-add-new-services-into-ambari.html) in hortonworks community, I have tried everything mentioned in that thread but unable to fix it. My sandbox is installed in vmware workstation 12 player. I also tried to create and remove directory manually but it is failing with the error invalid argument. Created a thread for this error also on [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317130/unable-to-delete-a-directory-from-vmware). Please help!!!

Comment: Hi, you commented on the related issue in [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317130/unable-to-delete-a-directory-from-vmware#comment558594_317130) that the main Ambari issue was resolved. Can you please post that solution here to help others who may encounter the same problem?

Comment: @Andy Totally forgot to response, I normally don't do that. The answer is found out here https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/62271/unable-to-add-apache-nifi-in-ambari.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/62271/unable-to-add-apache-nifi-in-ambari.html) to Hortonworks forum thread. And it seems like sandbox is just broken:

> This is due to a docker issue in this 2.5 sandbox build. It will be
>   fixed in next revision of the sandbox.

There are also some workarounds described (like use older HDP 2.4 or establishing own cluser based on the HDP 2.5 docker image)

Updated sandbox arrived: http://hortonworks.com/downloads

Answer (score -1):

Trust me, active member of community see your posts in multiple locations. In a good, no Big Brother ways :) but cross-posting is an old as world ... Well, you got it.

Did you see a notice for this service in Ambari? Telling it's been deprecated? Same note in the github. There's a good reason for that, it's now been implemented properly by the dev team and with many more features. I.e. all the action is there now.

I think I replied a similar question, though not sure it was yours, take a look in HCC.

Comment: it is not my question. Secondly I trust StackOverflow because I had always got the best help in this community. I don't think active members of StackOverflow and HCC are same on this tag, there might be a chance that at least one percent members are different and I don't think there is anything wrong in taking that chance. Also I don't see any notice regarding deprecation of any services of Ambari which I had used.